# Why does the VS 2015 Web Api project template not use app.UseWebApi Extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

All world is using the IAppBuilder extension UseWebApi together with asp.net web api. All the blog samples show it.

But When I create a web api project with VS 2015 RC I do not find anywhere the UseWebApi extension method used.

Why is that?

Comment: Are you looking at the correct samples? Eg [Create a Web API in MVC 6](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6) does *not* have this call, it only has `UseMVC`. Web API was rolled up into MVC 6 so you don't even have to use different controllers any more

Comment: What is a correct sample... ? I look at what Microsoft gives me in return pressing the "Create web api project template"-button. And there is no UseWebApi call. But everyone in web api 2.2 is doing it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the samples but I suspect you are targeting .NET 4.6. ASP.NET 4.6 projects use the new version MVC , 6 which incorporates Web API. You need to explicitly target  NET 4.5.2 in order to create a Web API 2.2 project.

Comment: ah now I remember again I did .NET 4.6 + web api and ripped out the not needed MVC references :P

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos according to this source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/04/30/updates-for-asp-net-4-6-web-forms-mvc-5-web-api-2.aspx .NET 4.6 projects are still MVC5 as I read it..., MVC6 is the new vNEXT.

Comment: Which means that you probably created a vNext project.

Comment: Actually NOT... than I would have a gulp or grunt and json file in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add the NuGet package “Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin” to get the extension method.

Comment: It is questionable to Microsoft why do I have to add a nuget package ending with .Owin why the project template has an Owin Startup class? This looks like a project template bug. "They forgot to add a package" This is not a question about a missing package. It is why does the project template not make use of .UseWebApi ?